# Custom URL Creation with .htaccess File and PHP

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Let website link is www.abc.com I have 3 PHP Files.

1. index.php
2. profile.php
3. group.php

My Current URL is -

1. abc.com/directory/index.php
2. abc.com/directory/profile.php?name=piash
3. abc.com/directory/group.php?name=CSE

I want to convert it to-

1. abc.com/home
2. abc.com/piash or abc.com/abrar (piash and abrar is GET parameter to profile.php file)
3. abc.com/group/CSE (CSE is the GET parameter to group.php)

I am using RAW PHP.

Is it possible?

If possible, how and where to put the .htaccess file?

In the root (abc.com) or in the folder (abc.com/directory) ?

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, it's definitely possible using an .htaccess file. You could also have all requests go to index.php and handle the request using routing. Have you made any attempts of your own yet?

Comment: But, how can I do it?

What is the code?

Comment: No no, that's not how this works. Where is your code you've used to attempt this?

Comment: .htaccess file doesn't use php code. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php). Attempt it yourself, show us what you got if it doesn't work, then come back here, posting your .htaccess code.

Comment: P.S. I have done a similar thing with my site, so I do know the answer. But you _need_ to at least try yourself, otherwise  you will learn nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in **your `/directory/.htaccess` file**:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory/

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L,NC]

# ignore files/directories from further rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^group/([^/]+)/?$ group.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: But where to put the .htaccess file?